# Pm2 Restart Node.js Process After Changing node_args

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ubuntu, pm2

If a Nodejs process was started from reading a PM2 JSON config file `pm2.json` file containing:

```
    {
      "name": "foobar",
      "script": "./foobar.js",
      "args": "-e baz",
      "node_args": "--max_old_space_size=1024"
    },
```

and `node_args` was modified resulting in

```
    {
      "name": "foobar",
      "script": "./foobar.js",
      "args": "-e baz",
      "node_args": "--max_old_space_size=2048"
    },
```

will the new `node_args` be applied by simply restarting the process with `pm2 restart <id>`?

Or do we have to do `pm2 delete <id>` followed by `pm2 start pm2.json`?

Answer (score 1):

Any action (start, restart, reload, stop) applied to the PM2 JSON configuration file will be passed to the processes.if you restart, all defined processes within that file get restarted immediately with new args.